# How to pop the bottomsheet dialog when navigating from one bottomsheet to another using jetpack navigation component

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have nav stack with a fragment and 2 bottomsheetdialogfragment. This is how my nav graph looks like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/football_home"
    android:id="@+id/home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/football_home"
        android:name="com.football.mib.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/launch_otl_link_prompt"
            app:destination="@+id/initial_flow"/>
    </fragment>

    <dialog android:id="@+id/initial_flow"
        android:name="com.football.mib.ui.consent.LinkPromptFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_initial_flow"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_link_prompt">

        <action android:id="@+id/activate_game"
            app:popUpTo="@id/game_activated"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"
            app:destination="@id/game_activated"/>

    </dialog>

    <dialog android:id="@+id/game_activated"
        android:name="com.football.mib.ui.consent.GameActivatedFragment"
        android:label="@string/game_activated"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game_activated" />

</navigation>
```

I can easily navigate between the fragments and dialogs, however I need to pop the previous bottomsheet when navigating to the second one. I have tried using `app:popUpTo` and `app:popUpToInclusive` but the first dialog `initial_flow` is still available in the backstack and dismissing the second dialog `game_activated` brings it to top again.

I also tried to invoke popUp programmatically via navOptions when navigating to second dialog to no avail e.g

```
binding.activateOneTap.setOnClickListener {
        val navOptions = navOptions {
            popUpTo(R.id.game_activated) {
                inclusive = true
            }
        }
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.activate_game, null, navOptions)
    }
```

I am using navigation component 2.3.4.

Any hints or alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, issue was because of using next dialog id instead of current dialog in the `app:popUpTo`. Updating the id resolved the problem.

```
<action android:id="@+id/activate_game"
            app:popUpTo="@id/initial_flow"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"
            app:destination="@id/game_activated"/>
```